# opengl functions are undefined

Tags: visual-c++, opengl

i got  a code of 3D hanoy game (`using opengl ,glut`). when i try to run this game using VS 12 ,following errors
are showing ---

```
glutTimerFunc is undefined

glutInit is undefined


glutWindowSize is undefined 

glPushMatrix is undefined

glRotatef  is undefined

glTranslatef is undefined

glutSolidTorus is undefined

glPopMatirx is undefined
```

as i guess these problems are about missing functions , how can i add these functions in my code to run it  ?

Comment: Have you include your glut libraries into your project?

Comment: i think so ......i again run it ,now its showing "can't open file :gl/glut.h "

Comment: It should be library path & header path issue. You can find a GLUT on Visual Studio tutorial and see what you did wrong, like this one: http://ins.nafsadh.com/2009/09/07/opengl-and-glut-in-c-with-ms-visual-studio-2008-msvs9/

Answer (score -1):

Follow [this](http://cacs.usc.edu/education/cs596/OGL_Setup.pdf) or [this](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/glut/) tutorial that introduces you to the basics of building an application using GLUT.

Hope it helps